# TypeScript eslint: Rule to prevent same naming of interface

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

In TypeScript defining multiple interfaces with same name is allowed:

```
export interface Person {
  fullName: string;
}

export interface Person {
  name: string;
}
```

Is there an eslint rule to give a warning when this is encountered?

Comment: Overloading is a feature not a flaw to lint

Comment: @makeitmorehuman function overloading is a very useful feature but what is the use case of interface overloading?

Comment: This is not overloading, this is called declaration merging. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces

Comment: He beat me to it :)

Comment: Just because it's a feature doesn't mean its unreasonable to choose to not use it on a specific project. It is a easy to make mistakes where you think you're defining a new interface where in fact you're merging into a previously defined one. I'd personally like to prevent this with eslint, and just eslint-disable-next line if/when I have a valid use case for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

typescript-eslint turns this check off to add support for TypeScript function overloads, and declaration merging. You can override to turn it back on in your own rules by reenabling `no-redeclare`:

```
module.exports = {
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-redeclare": "off",
    "no-redeclare": "warn",
  }
};
```

We have chosen to turn this on to avoid mistakes, while understanding that we can always ignore at the file or block level when we want to intentionally merge interfaces.

See https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-redeclare/ for details.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is possible as this is a core feature of TS.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You have declared an interface. Interfaces are great for declaring what properties and functions the outside world can see on an object. What they don't do is allow you you to add any implementation detail.
The implementation detail either comes in the forms of functions or classes.
You currently have a function, but want to implement it on the object itself. For that you can create a class that implements the interface. I would recommend that you keep your interface, and pass that around where possible. The code that consumes an `IPersonItem` doesn't care how `fullName` has been implemented, just that it exists.

```
export interface IPersonItem {
  _id?: number;
  name: string;
  lastName: string;
  fullName: string;
}
export class PersonItem implements IPersonItem {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public lastName: string,
    public _id?: number
  ) {
  }
get fullName() { return `${this.name} ${this.lastName}`; }
}
```

Some example usage

```
export class MyService {
  getPersonItem(): IPersonItem {
    return new PersonItem('first', 'last', 123);
  }
}
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const person: IPersonItem = this.myService.getPersonItem();
    console.log(person.fullName); // "first last"
  }
}
```